# Difference between using -build all and -build .* in eclipsec command?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting different results while using -build all and -build .* to build my headless cdt projects
How does eclipse see these two options? how do they differ?

Comment: I have given an answer, but without explanation about what is the difference in what you are actually seeing it is hard to say. In the [source](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core//src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/internal/core/HeadlessBuilder.java?h=cdt_9_2#n510) `buildAll` is true if `all` is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most significant difference is that `all` builds the workspace rather than iterating over projects. It builds the workspace with "Build All Configurations" preference set to true. Therefore non CDT projects will be built too with `all`.

Additionally, the order of the build may be different, `all` should be respecting the workspace build order, while specifying projects with regular expressions will only respect dependency order.

Comment: Can I get more information on difference between workspace build order and dependency order

Comment: Workspace order is a preference in Windows -> Preferences. The workspace order should derive from dependency order. Dependency order is calculated based on project references set in the individual project properties.